# Citation: Author (Year)

Tags: citing, mendeley

I'm starting a redacting an article for my career. I have created my database of references in a `.bib` file, Mendeley exports my reference list. When I cite a reference Mendeley put (Author, year) but I would like to cite like this "according to Author (year)" as in the picture below.

How can I achieve this citation style?

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Mendeley is unimportant here, it is how you do your bibliography with LaTeX. Have a look at [biblatex and biber](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber)

Comment: Assuming you're using BibTeX, which citation management package(s) do you load (if any), and which bibliography style do you employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of natbib package `\usepackage{natbib}`

`\citet{Erdos65}` will give your desired output. The folowing are the list of other options and also go through this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies

```
\citet{Erdos65} will produce Erdős et al. (1965)
\citet[chapter 2]{Erdos65}  produces    Erdős et al. (1965, chapter 2)
\citet[pp. 10-12]{Erdos65}  produces    Erdős et al. (1965, pp. 10-12)
\citet[see][chap. 2]{Erdos65}   produces    Erdős et al. (see 1965, chap. 2)

\citep{Erdos65} produces    (Erdős et al. 1965)
\citep[chapter 2]{Erdos65}  produces    (Erdős et al. 1965, chapter 2)
\citep[pp. 10-12]{Erdos65}  produces    (Erdős et al. 1965, pp. 10-12)
\citep[see][chap. 2]{Erdos65}   produces    (see Erdős et al. 1965, chap. 2)
\citep[e.g.][]{Erdos65} produces    (e.g. Erdős et al. 1965)
```

Comment: Please add that package `natbib` has to be loaded for commands `\citet` and `\citep` ...

Comment: Thanks for your time and recomendations TVM Boy.